# When to use dot files in Git repositories?

Tags: project-structure, file-systems

My Git repository contains dot files required by my tooling:

- `.dockerignore`
- `.gitignore`
- `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

I'm using Azure Pipelines for CI/CD, which is typically defined in `azure-pipelines.yml`, but this is customizable.

I've noticed that other CI/CD tools use dot files:

- `.github/workflows/`
- `.gitlab-ci.yml`
- `.travis.yml`

This makes me question whether I should use `.azure-pipelines.yml`.

When should I use dot files or dot directories? I understand that dot files are used to hide the file or directory, so when should I hide a file or directory? Should I just use the common conventions of the tooling?

Comment: If Azure Pipelines for CI/CD typically uses `azure-pipelines.yml` then go with that, unless you feel compelled to customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the principle of least astonishment: Unless you have a good reason to change them, use the default file names that your tools expect.

That will also be the names that other developers will expect to find if they know you use those tools and they need to make a change to the tool's settings.